# How to fix a specific time for a method in java

Tags: java, user-interface, timer

I am writing a code in Java, that has three main methods which are called in succession. Today, my prof, told me to improve the code by setting a frequency to code which means it that there should be a specific time allocated for each method. If it is done before that time, it should wait for that much time and then call should go to next method.

For example: If the first method has time of 3 seconds, for three seconds it should wait there even if it is done, then move to next method sense.

I am already using a timer in my code to slow down the movement as it is a GUI. I was planning to use another timer, but I feel it will only slow it down. How can I fix the period for that method for a specific time say 3 seconds.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code. Right now the question is too broad for this forum.

Comment: Try using Thread.sleep()

Comment: @PM77-1 The code is too big to post, I just want to know if timer is to be used for fixed time delay, if not what can be used

Comment: @Santiago I tried Thread.sleep(), but the GUI freezes and all I see is final output after all the three methods have run

Comment: @Santiago - Never sleep on EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) in Swing.

Comment: Unless you provide a detailed context for your question, it has good chances to be closed rather quickly.

Comment: @PM77-1 What more information do you require for this post? I can explain more if you can tell me which area is not clear

Comment: @learningJava If you provide a SSCCE, we are able to you fix what is not working and, it helps the community avoid simply doing someone's homework.  There are a lot of possible answers here, many of which will start with an assumption.  Your code would serve as a great starting point.  Are you trying to delay your functions in the EDT?  Do you even know what that is?  How is your "other" thread working?  An SSCCE would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot sleep on your own thread, run the task on another thread. A single executor thread will do nicely, to which you can submit tasks to be executed. Sleeping in the executor thread should not impact the GUI thread.

```
private Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

public void method1() {
    System.out.println("Method 1 called");
}

public void method2() {
    System.out.println("Method 2 called");
}

public void method3() {
    System.out.print("Method 3 called");
}

public void start() {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        private final long WAIT_TIME = 3000; // ms

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            method1();
            sleep(startTime);

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            method2();
            sleep(startTime);

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            method3();
            sleep(startTime);
        }

        private void sleep(long startTime) {
            long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            long timeLeft = WAIT_TIME - timeTaken;
            if(timeLeft < 0) return;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeLeft);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
}
```